# MySQL opensource Performance monitoring tools

Tags: mysql, monitoring

Is there any opensource tools for monitoring MySQL performance.

It should be like 
1) where exactly the server is loaded 
2) what is the performance of each and every query that access DB. 
3) Graphical View of the performance using piecharts, bardiagrams etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools which you can use, some of them are paid

1. [MONyog MySQL Monitor](https://www.webyog.com/)
2. [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)
3. [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit)

There are also other tools and tips [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/).

Comment: I think MONyog MySQL monitor & MySQL Enterprise Monitor are not opensource tools

Comment: Thank you Sharique, i have found JetProfiler which is also licensed, but i have tried the free version, it is good(looking for this kind of tool) . If you know any other Opensource tools for MySQL performance monitoring please post

Comment: Any update on the opensource tools?

Comment: Hi Sasikiran,

Navicat recently released Navicat Monitor. (https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-monitor)  It's definitely the best monitoring tool for MySQL.  It employs an agentless architecture so that you don't have to install any software on your DB servers.  

It includes both real-time and historical graphs that allow you to drill down into server statistic details.  Other features include, alerts, reporting, Query Analyzer, and Replication monitoring.